# Can not connect sony g3311 to eclipse, no drivers available

Tags: android, eclipse, driver, sony

I have a g3311 (xperia L1) and I want to use it for debugging android apps in eclipse. I have installed the Xperia companion software on the computer so now it shows up in that software and in Windows explorer when the phone is connected via USB. I cannot however see it in eclipse->devices (even after restart) and in the Windows device manager it shows up with an exclamation mark complaining about no driver.

I have looked at Sony's page for drivers: https://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/ the Xperia L1 or G3311 is not in it.. I have also read a lot of similar questions here on stackoverflow but they all refer to steps including downloading the adb driver... which seems to be non existent so if anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this I would appreciate it

Comment: Why don't you try Android Studio as suggested by @oğuzhan-döngül?

Comment: Irrelevant, or are you saying that I can use the g3311 in Android studio without a driver??

Comment: As you said you have already installed Xperia Companion Software your device should detect in Android Studio without any problem. If not use [ADB Driver Installer](http://adbdriver.com/). (I am not the down-voter) and please tell me which OS you're using?

Comment: Thank you I will try ADB Driver Installer, I am on Win7 (before anyone says anything, I know Win10 exists..)

Comment: Device shows up in eclipse under devices after using ADB Driver Installer. But, its state and target is Unknown so I still can not run and apps on it. When I launch an android app I can select the device but the "OK" button is grayed out in "Android Device Chooser"

Comment: unplugging and re-plugging the phone a few times seems to have done the trick, I was now also able to select the File Transfer Mode on the phone. If you want to make an answer for this I will accept it, thanks again.

Comment: No as you found the solution by yourself post the self answer. But still I suggest you to use Android Studio. Best of luck.

Comment: It is not irrelevant. Your problem may be usb socket problem but, Eclipse may not see higher API levels due to lack of support some cases. And you must move on with Android Studio in near future.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `Eclipse` for `Android developing`, it's slow and lack of tools.
Also Eclipse support has ended by `Google` officially.

> With the release of Android Studio 2.2, the time has now come to say goodbye to the Eclipse Android Developer Tools. We have formally ended their support and development. There's never been a better time to switch to Android Studio and experience the improvements we've made to the Android development workflow.

[Source](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.tr/2016/11/support-ended-for-eclipse-android.html)

Use Android Studio.

**UPDATE**

Install XPERIA Companion to your PC and connect it. Then open Android Studio or Eclipse.

Comment: Wow, You do not answer the question at all and you have clearly not even read the question, proven by your update..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows 8, Android Studio 3.0.1.

Installing adb drivers via [ADB Driver Installer](http://adbdriver.com/) solved this issue.

Thanks to [Shashanth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5180017/shashanth)